# Отфильтровать все не int значения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
let str = '{"f", 3, 5, 1}';
```

Есть такая вот строка я пытаюсь отфильтровать все значения кроме int
делаю это таким образом

```
console.log(str.replace(/[^}{,\d]/g, ''));
```

На выходе я получаю

```
"{,3,5,1}"
```

Как можно переписать регулярное выражение, что бы если находилось не int значение оно убирало еще и лишнюю запятую
Т.е. надо получить на выходе  `"{3,5,1}"`

Думаю заменить все `,,`, на `,`
`{,` на `{`
и так далее но это похоже на костыль + это не надежно, так же думал разделить по , и откинуть пустые значения и составить новую строку, но может быть это можно сделать регуляркой?

Comment: Если нет чисел в строках, ``console.log(`{${str.match(/\d+/g).join(", ")}}`)`` может подойти.

Comment: Это шедевр!! Спасибо